# In PHP, how do I find out what $this is referring to?

Tags: php, class, oop, joomla, this

I've been bugged by `$this` for a long time. Many times when I try to read some Joomla snippet I come across `$this` here and there. 
I understand in definition of a class, `$this` refers to the instance of the class. But what does it mean when `$this` is not in a definition?
Like this:

```
echo $this->loadTemplate('item')
```

and this:

```
<?php if ($this->params->get('teacher_studylist', '1') == '1')
{  if ($this->message->teachername) {?>
<div class="teacher"><?php echo JText::_('COM_PREACHIT_by');?> <span><?php echo $this->message->teachername;?></span></div>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

My second question is, in Javascript, if I am confused with what "this" is, I can always go to browers' console and hover my mouse on the "this", and what it is referring to will appear. But In PHP, is there any way to do the similar things?(If I had known a way to do it, I might be able to solve the problem by myself not having to ask for help here)

Comment: `$this` likely refers to a Joomla super-global which can be used to call upon various loaded classes and object items such as `params` or `message`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
get_class($this);
```

To find out the origination of your `$this`

Answer (score 3):

From [the docs](http://docs.joomla.org/J1.5%3aTemplate_parameters):

> Note that the $this object in the template is always the current instance of the JDocument object. Also note that $this->params is an object of type JParameter.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried to search for $this in the docs but there were just too many results to find my answer. Could you please tell me how you got to that page?
However, I've still got a question. Those "$this"s in my main question are not in a template, and the result of "get_class" is not Jdocument. So how do I tell a $this is "in the template" or not?

Comment: I searched for "joomla template $this", I just assumed it was a template because of the HTML; those docs look out of date actually, I think the the template class is called `JDocumentHTML` now. I'm not too familiar with joomla so I'm just guessing, but you can actually use `get_class()` to _tell_ that you're in a template by what type of object's scope you're currently in (if it's a `JDocumentHTML` for example)